# Why does normal-ordering ensure finiteness?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, fermions, regularization, bosonization

I will be using [Jan von Delft's](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9805275v3) rigorous construction of bosonization/refermionization as an example, but I will try to explain my question in more general terms.

Consider an (countably) infinite-dim (single-particle) Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ and let $\mathcal F$ denote the corresponding fermion Fock space. Since $\mathcal F$ is infinite-dim, operators which are the sum of products of creation/annihilation operators, e.g.,
$$
A=\sum \psi_i^\dagger \psi_j a_{ij} + \psi_i^\dagger \psi_j^\dagger b_{ij} + \psi_i \psi_j^\dagger c_{ij}
$$
may be ill-defined since the infinite-summation may not converge. In von Delft, such operators are regularized by requiring that each product in the summation must be normal-ordered with respect to the ground state/vacuum state, and this does seem to regularize the quantities mentioned in bosonization/refermionization.

However, in general, there must be some other conditions on the coefficients $a_{ij},b_{ij},c_{ij}$ so that the summation is well-defined. What are such conditions?